# Basic goroutine and channel pattern: multiple goroutines for one channel

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine, channel

i'm new to Go and am wondering about some pretty basic problem that i can't figure out clearly.

Just for the exercize (an abstraction of a real need), i need to:

- initialize a slice of string with a number of elements fixed by the constant `ITERATIONS`
- iterate over this slice and run a goroutine for each element
- each goroutine will take a certain amount of time to process the element (a random second duration)
- once the job is finished, i want the goroutine to push the result to a channel
- then i need to catch all the results from this channel (in a function called from the main goroutine), append them to the final slice and then, once its finished
- print the length of the final slice and add some basic time tracking

Below is a code that works.

No surprise, the total amount of program time is always more or less equals to const MAX_SEC_SLEEP's value, as all the processing goroutine do they work in parallel.

But what about:

1. the receive part:

do i really need to wrap my select statement in a for loop, iterating the exact amount of ITERATIONS , to have the exact same number of receivers than the number of goroutines that will end to the channel ? Is it the only way to avoid deadlock here ? And what if for some reason, one of the goroutine fails ?

I can't find a way to have a simple for (ever) loop wrapping the select, with two cases (the one receiving from the results channel and another one like `case <-done` that wouldreturn from the function). Would it be a better pattern ?

Or would it be better to iterate over the channel and detect if it is closes from somewhere ?

2. the send part

Should i close somewhere the channel, after all the iterations ? but i would surely close it before at least one of the gouroutine finishes, ending in a panic error (trying to send to a closed channel)

If i were to plug a `done <- true` pattern, would it be here ?

3. Wait groups

i did not really try waitgroups, ad i need a way to catch all 'return' values from the goroutines and append them to the final slice; and i did not find a proper way to return from a goroutine except by using channels.

4. Misc

Should i pass channels in func arguments or let them global to the program as it is ?

5. The (bad) code

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

const ITERATIONS = 200

var (
    results   chan string
    initial   []string
    formatted []string
)

func main() {
    defer timeTrack(time.Now(), "program")

    format()  //run format goroutines
    receive() //receive formatted strings

    log.Printf("final slice contains %d/%d elements", len(formatted), len(initial))
}

//gets all results from channel and appends them to formatted slice
func receive() {
    for i := 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ {
        select {
        case result := <-results:
            formatted = append(formatted, result)
        }
    }
}

//loops over initial slice and runs a goroutine per element
//that does some formatting operation and then pushes result to channel
func format() {
    for i := 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            //simulate some formatting code that can take a while
            sleep := time.Duration(rand.Intn(10)) * time.Second
            time.Sleep(sleep)
            //append formatted string to result chan
            results <- fmt.Sprintf("%s formatted", initial[i])
        }(i)
    }

}

//initialize chans and inital slice
func init() {
    results = make(chan string, ITERATIONS)
    for i := 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++ {
        initial = append(initial, fmt.Sprintf("string #%d", i))
    }
}

func timeTrack(start time.Time, name string) {
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    log.Printf("%s took %s", name, elapsed)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find a way to have a simple for (ever) loop wrapping the select, with two cases (the one receiving from the results channel and another one like case <-done that wouldreturn from the function). Would it be a better pattern ?

If the channel is closed once all writers are done, you can use a simple `for ... range` loop:

```
for result := range ch {
    ... do something with the result ...
}
```

In order for this simple variant to work, the channel *must* become closed, otherwise the `for` loop will not terminate.

> Should i close somewhere the channel, after all the iterations ?

If at all possible, yes.

> i did not really try waitgroups ...

A `sync.WaitGroup`, or something very similar, is almost certainly the way to go here.  Each goroutine that can write *to* the channel should be accounted for initially, e.g.:

```
var wg Sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(ITERATIONS)
```

Then you can just spawn all your goroutines that write and let them run.  As each runs, it calls `wg.Done()` to indicate that it is finished.

You then—somewhere; the *where* part is slightly tricky—call `wg.Wait()` to wait for all of the writers to be done.  When all the writers indicate that they are done, you can `close()` the channel.

Note that if you call `wg.Wait()` from the *same* goroutine that is reading the channel—i.e., the goroutine that will run the `for result := range ...` loop—you have a problem: you cannot simultaneously read from the channel *and* wait for the writers to write to the channel.  So you either have to call `wg.Wait()` after the loop finishes, which is too late; or before the loop starts, which is too early.

This makes the problem and its solution clear: you must read from the channel in one goroutine, and do the wait-and-then-close in another goroutine.  At most one of these goroutines can be the main one that entered the `main` function originally.

It tends to be pretty simple to make the wait-and-then-close goroutine its own private one:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(results)
}()
```

for instance.

> what if for some reason, one of the goroutine fails?

You'll need to define precisely what you mean by *fails* here, but if you mean: what if the called goroutine itself calls, say, `panic` and therefore does not get to its `wg.Done()` call, you can use `defer` to make sure the `wg.Done()` happens even on a panic:

```
func(args) {
    defer wg.Done()
    ... do the work ...
}

wg.Add(1)
go func(args) // `func` will definitely call `wg.Done`, even if `func` panics
```

> Should i pass channels in func arguments or let them global to the program as it is ?

Stylistically, global variables are always a bit messy.  This does not mean you *cannot* use them; it's up to you, just keep all the tradeoffs in mind.  Closure variables are not as messy, but remember to be careful with `for` loop iteration variables:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println(i)  // BEWARE BUG: this prints 10, not 0-9
    }()
}
```

behaves badly.  [Try this on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TLuJMBPmQ8P); note that `go vet` now complains about the bad use of `i` here.

I took your original sample code over to the Go Playground and made minimal changes to it as described above.  The result is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/9Dao4GdyW7t).  (To make it less slow I made the sleeps wait n-hundred-milliseconds instead of n seconds.)